# how to iterate excel values in pywinauto automation script

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl, ui-automation, pywinauto

In the below code i am trying to read stream names from excel one by one and play all the streams continuously automatically using pywinauto...but i could read all streams from excel and print it  but play only the first stream... How to play set of streams continuously?

[image]

```
filename = "read_output_sheet.xlsx"

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
sheet1 = wb.worksheets[0]
sheet1.title = "TEST_SHEET_1"

def play():
    global stream_name
    path=os.path.realpath("D:\\STREAMS\PCM") 
    os.startfile(path) # open the folder named "pcm_streams"
    app = pywinauto.Desktop(backend='uia').window(best_match='PCM')
    time.sleep(1)
    win = app.window(title_re = stream_name, found_index=0) #'pcm48k_org'   str(stream_name)
    time.sleep(1)
    win.click_input(button='left')
    win.click_input(button='right') # right click on one file listed there
    app1 = pywinauto.Desktop(backend='uia').window(best_match='ContextMenu',top_level_only = True)
    win1 = app1.window(title_re="Open with")#Open with
    win1.click_input()  # click on "Open with" context menu
    app2 = Desktop(backend='win32')
    app2.PopupMenu.menu_item('foobar2000').click_input()
    
    
row_num = 3
i = 1
while(1):
    if sheet1.cell(i + row_num, 3).value is None:
        break
        
    else:
        stream_name = sheet1.cell(i + row_num, 3).value 
        print(stream_name)      
        play()  
        i +=1

wb.save(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, why use Pywinauto to do this.
Use **xlwings** is more natural:

```py
import xlwings as xw
book=xw.Book('test.xlsx')
one=book.sheets[0]
for a in range(7):
    column=chr(ord('A')+a)
    for b in range(1,12):
        c=one[f'{column}{b}'].value
        print(c, end=' ')
    print()
```

[image]